# Pick random strings from string.xml

Tags: android

I've just started out with android and write a simple dialog app with some random strings presented to the user. I started to think about best way to do that?

if strings.xml consist of strings like:

```
<string name="quote1">blaha blaha</string>
<string name="quote2">chit chat</string>
```

I guess there's a better way then generating a random int and then do

```
case 1:
   R.id.quote1
```

I guess it will end up with at least 50 different quotes in that file, that's one ugly switch ..

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load your quotes into a list structure via xpath, select a random index from the list.  Display that quote.

Alternately, get the count of quotes from the xml document, get a random index within that range, select the xml node at that index, and display it.

Answer (score 3):

Try to get your quotes into a [String array](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray)

Comment: You may want to explain a step further for explicitness: Then you can load the whole array into your activity with the getStringArray resources method (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getStringArray(int)) and randomly select from the array without the need for explicitly coding a switch for every resource ID. This is almost certainly the easiest way to go.

Comment: Sounds great, I'll try that out for sure!

Answer (score 1):

If you cant use [String Array](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray) then do this:

All .xml descriptor files in Android get compiled to `your.package.R` class.

You can use [Java Reflection](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/) to inspect this class at runtime. In your case `R.id` is an inner static class.

```
Class clazz = R.id.class;
Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();

// chose random field
int rnd = (int) (fields.length * Math.random());
String randomString = getString(fields[rnd].getInt(null));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only two strings its pretty simple, right. But if you have more, you might want to think about making a string array. You can make  in XML easily.

Then just choose stringarray[random_number] as your string.

Answer (score -1):

There's a way to select a random item from a sequential list without knowing the length of the list.

The algorithm is:

```
numItems = 0;
selectedItem = null;
while not end of list
{
  item = read item from list
  numItems = numItems+1;
  if (numItems == 1)
    selectedItem = item;
  else  if (random(numItems) == 0)
    selectedItem = item
}
```

The idea is that there is always a 1/numItems probability that the new item will replace the currently selected item.

For more information, see my article [Random Selection from Large Groups](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=796).  Scroll down to "What if I don't know how many there are?"  The code is in C#, but the discussion is language agnostic.